# Is there any difference between FTP and SFTP regarding content cache mechanism

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, jsch, hxtt

We are using hxtt jdbc driver to load files from server

**What is HXTT CSV driver**  : hxtt driver is used treat file as database tables allow user to fetch the data using SQL Queries

Example : Employee.csv file having following record

**EmpID**, **EmpName**

Suraj, 001

Pankaj, 002

Now, I can fetch this simple sql Query : **select * from Employee;**

We are using FTP and SFTP protocol to load files from remote server. connection is successful But we are facing strange issue.

**Issue :**

1. We have 2 columns in our file now I discover these columns in my product, its successfully discovered 2 columns
2. Now If I update file with new Column, and try to discover its not getting updated one column

Same scenarios works fine with FTP and SMB protocol

- **Web-Server we are using** : Apache Tomcat
- **Java 8**
- **SFTP client is inside hxtt jar file**
- **We are using JSCH jar to connect to SFTP server**

So, I was wondering is there anything from protocol itself that not allowing to get updates results from file ?

Comment: No there's nothing in the protocol itself that would cause this. + Unless you can retrieve the correct version of the file with any SFTP client, but not in Java JSch SFTP code, this is not a programming question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Thanks. But I was surprised that exact same scenario works perfectly fine for FTP and SMB. Why its not fetching for SFTP ?

I tried to find on net but didn't get much info about caching in SFTP

Comment: There's no caching "in SFTP", as such. You particular SFTP server may do some caching. But you didn't tell us anything about your SFTP server. And it's not a programming question anyway,